# What guitar chord is this?

Tags: guitar, chords

Tony Joe White played Rainy night in Georgia ( Germany '92 ). I'm wondering what chord is this? The chord is at 1min:30sec on video:

Comment: Looks like it could be a maj7 but frankly it's too hard to hear and too hard to see.  I cannot tell if the thumb is being used to fret a note in the bass or just his hand posture.  Try looking at a chord chart and comparing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty clearly a Gmaj7 chord with fingering (from low E to high e):

`X X 5 4 3 2`

It's the IV chord of the key, coming from a Dmaj7 chord.

Comment: It looks very much like his pinky is on the A string. Probably a trick of foreshortening. The Gmaj7 jibes better with "fake book" chord lists based on the timing in the verse.

Comment: Yes it's Gmaj7. I looked at the chords here: https://tabs.ultimate-guitar.com/tab/tony_joe_white/rainy_night_in_georgia_chords_1502755, and they put G major but it didn't sound like the one Tony played. He was muting sixt & fifth strings with his thumb and that was clearly Gmaj7. Thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

Difficult to make out exactly with the microphone in the way, but the position of the pinky especially makes it look like a loosely-barred "open-C" pattern starting at the second fret, which would make it a D.

[image]

But it looks like he is muting with the index finger, and possibly leaving the G string open, more like:

[image]

The internet says that the song is in D. There are multiple versions where some chord lists claim  plain D maj, others using different variations of D.

Comment: I don't see the index being flattened.  Though it's hard to tell, which is why I didn't answer.